# Please specify the product's option(s) in Magento

Tags: magento

Actually i am using Elias_configurablebundle plugin for the configurable product as associated of the Bundle Product and to display *GRID** for the configurable associated products i am using magento mechanics grid. here i have merged both of the extensions it showing **GRID** on bundle view page but showing **Please specify the product's option(s)* on click of the **Add To Cart**.

Although everything is fine, no required field left to fill out, i have applied any single custom options for any of the product.

so here i want to remove this validation so then it will directly redirect to shopping cart page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configurable products need to have their options chosen (say, color or size) in order to be added to the cart. Otherwise, there is no way to decide which simple product should be decremented from the inventory. So there is no way for you to "skip" selecting this information, other than hardcoding the selections for the configurable product.

If you do that, just use the simple products instead, and skip all the headache.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I have same problem please describe me more,how to i can solve it

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is that the options fields are actually inside the  tags. Its fairly easy in Magento to move the option selects to a different column and not realize that you are moving them outside the add to cart form tags.

if the options are selected outside the form tags, then as far as the form is concerned no options have been selected.

Hope this helps someone down the road.